# Using Left() with Drupal Custom Module

Tags: database

I'm trying to return only the first 200 characters (if there are more than that) from a body field in a Drupal custom module. I've found the general php/mysql solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080860/mysql-sql-retrieve-first-40-characters-of-a-text-field

But when I try to implement it with my SQL query in my custom module it doesn't work (ie. it still returns over 200 characters). Here's my code (see the field I used LEFT() on is LEFT(fdb.body_value, 200) on line 6):

```
$result = db_query(
"SELECT n.title, n.nid, n.status, 
fdfty.field_type_value, fdfi.entity_id, 
fdfi.field_icon_fid, fm.uri, fm.fid, ua.pid, 
ua.alias, el.field_experience_level_value, 
**LEFT(fdb.body_value, 200)**, 
fdfr.field_role_value, fdft.field_topics_value, 
fdfed.field_event_dates_value, 
fdfed.field_event_dates_value2
FROM {node} AS n 
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_type} AS fdfty 
ON n.nid=fdfty.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_icon} AS fdfi 
ON n.nid=fdfi.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN {file_managed} AS fm 
ON fdfi.field_icon_fid=fm.fid 
LEFT JOIN {url_alias} AS ua 
ON n.nid=ua.pid 
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_experience_level} AS el 
ON n.nid=el.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN {field_data_body} AS fdb 
ON n.nid=fdb.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_role} AS fdfr
ON n.nid=fdfr.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_topics} AS fdft 
ON n.nid=fdft.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_event_dates} AS fdfed 
ON n.nid=fdfed.entity_id 
WHERE n.status=:status AND n.type=:resource 
AND (fdfty.field_type_value=:webinar OR fdfty.field_type_value=:conference) AND el.field_experience_level_value=:level 
AND fdfr.field_role_value=:role 
AND fdft.field_topics_value=:topic 
AND ((fdfed.field_event_dates_value IS NULL) 
OR (fdfed.field_event_dates_value >= CURRENT_DATE())) 
GROUP BY n.nid, n.title 
ORDER BY fdfed.field_event_dates_value", 
array(':status' => '1', ':resource' => 'resource',
':webinar' => 'Webinar', ':conference' => 'Conference', ':level' => $level, ':role' =>
$role, ':topic' => $topic));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use [substr()](http://php.net/substr) let the SQL statement bring it all then use this function in your result

would be something like this:

```
<?php

$result = db_query('Your SQL statement');

print substr($result, 0 , 199);

?>
```